Name of a 1930s romantic movie
There is an old movie I think in the 30s, where I remember 1 scene or 2 but don't know the name. I appreciate if you help me in finding the name.
There was a father in a village who has a daughter and he made her marry a man she doesn't know. So on their wedding day, he arrived very late on a donkey, and took her to his castle. She was arrogant, crazy, and her husband started to love her... 
So can you help me in finding the name?

Pretty sure you're talking about The Taming of the Shrew (1967) starring Elizabeth Taylor and Richard Burton. Or some other version of the famous Shakespeare play, or it's musical version Kiss Me, Kate.
I haven't seen the Taylor/Burton version in a while but I'm pretty sure that Petruchio's arrival for the wedding to Kate is very tardy and he arrives dressed very oddly.
He takes her back to his castle where he proceeds to "tame" her to be a dutiful wife and they eventually fall for each other.
There is a Mary Pickford & Douglas Fairbanks version from 1929 as well but I've not seen it.
